# Generate synthetic data given AUC

Tags: r, machine-learning, simulation, roc, auc

I'm experimenting with `ROC`-`AUC` for binary classification problems. I want to generate synthetic data for a given AUC score. The inputs of the problem are the following:

- A vector of labels, made of 0's and 1's.
- A given AUC, let's say `0.8`

I want to generate a vector of scores (preferably between `0` and `1`) that, with these labels, has the given `AUC`. I know the solution is not unique but I cannot think a way to generate such vector of scores. An implementation in `R` would be also great.

Comment: In the WORST case, remember that you can use “brute force” and ask R to simulate the scores and solve the reminder of the problem (the measurement of AUC) for each of the n simulations, and stop the simulation loop for k<n iff the measured AUC for the scores simulated at k is in a range very close to 0.8. It will be time-consuming but if you initialize and guide the solver in a reasonable way then the time to get there will be reduced, especially if for each iteration the volume of data is not excessively big. It’s like saying: R will make the hard work for me and will try until it gets there

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: This might be a shortcut.  I worked on a similar project and based my simulation on the reasonably good assumption that AUC will have a decent linear correlation (although the quadratic fit is better) with the R-squared between the two variables -- the continuous "score" and the binary "prediction."

Comment: I think you made a mistake and by predictions, you mean labels/targets and the scores are the predictions right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. One is to assume to transform AUC to cohen's D and then just sample data from 2 standard normal distributions D standard deviations apart.

We can transform AUC to D according to a formula from *SALGADO, Jesús F.. Transforming the Area under the Normal Curve (AUC) into Cohen’s d, Pearson’s r pb , Odds-Ratio, and Natural Log Odds-Ratio: Two Conversion Tables. The European Journal of Psychology Applied to Legal Context [online]. 2018, vol.10, n.1, pp.35-47. ISSN 1989-4007.  http://dx.doi.org/10.5093/ejpalc2018a5*

[image]

Which in R code will work like this

```
auc <- 0.95

t <- sqrt(log(1/(1-auc)**2))
z <- t-((2.515517 + 0.802853*t + 0.0103328*t**2) / 
          (1 + 1.432788*t + 0.189269*t**2 + 0.001308*t**3))
d <- z*sqrt(2)

n <- 10000
x <- c(rnorm(n/2, mean = 0), rnorm(n/2, mean = d))
y <- c(rep(0, n/2), rep(1, n/2))

library(AUC)
auc(roc(x, as.factor(y)))

# out
# [1] 0.9486257
```

Of course, since we are sampling, this will produce the correct AUC on average, but the specific sample will not be exactly the required AUC.

Comment: Copied this solution and added platt scaling at end for highly related question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562000/how-to-simulate-a-calibrated-prediction-model-given-prevalence-and-auc/565607#565607