# How to simulate a calibrated prediction model given prevalence and auc

Tags: r, predictive-models, simulation, beta-distribution, auc

I want to be able to simulate a prediction model given some prevalence of the event and the AUC of the model.  I followed the method proposed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422926/generate-synthetic-data-given-auc) but, although this works for giving AUC and predicted values, the predictions aren't well-calibrated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(AUC)

get_sample <- function(auc, n_samples, prevalence, scale=T){
  # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422926/generate-synthetic-data-given-auc
  t <- sqrt(log(1/(1-auc)**2))
  z <- t-((2.515517 + 0.802853*t + 0.0103328*t**2) / 
            (1 + 1.432788*t + 0.189269*t**2 + 0.001308*t**3))
  d <- z*sqrt(2)
  
  n_neg <- round(n_samples*(1-prevalence))
  n_pos <- round(n_samples*prevalence)
  
  x <- c(rnorm(n_neg, mean=0), rnorm(n_pos, mean=d))
  y <- c(rep(0, n_neg), rep(1, n_pos))
  
  if(scale){
    x <- (x-min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x))
  }
  return(data.frame(predicted=x, actual=y))
}

df_preds <- get_sample(auc=0.8, n_samples=2000, prevalence=0.1) %>%
  mutate(predicted_interval=cut(predicted, seq(0,1,0.1), labels=FALSE)/10-0.05)

# problem with this approach is that it doesn't lead to well calibrated predictions
df_preds %>%
  group_by(predicted_interval) %>%
  summarize(mean_actual=mean(actual)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(predicted_interval, mean_actual)) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline()+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 1)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1))
```

[image: sampling using previous AUC and Cohen's D]

To ensure that the predictions that I get are well-calibrated, I thought to sample from a beta-distribution and sample the outcome c(0,1) based on the given probability.

```
get_beta_preds <- function(alpha, beta, n){
  cat(glue::glue("population prevalence:{round(alpha/(alpha+beta), 4)}\n\n"))
  predicted_probs <- rbeta(n=n, shape1=alpha, shape2=beta)
  f <- function(x) sample(c(0, 1), 1, prob=c(1-x, x))
  predicted_classes <- map_dbl(predicted_probs, f)
  
  cat(glue::glue("observed AUC:{round(auc(roc(predicted_probs, as.factor(predicted_classes))), 4)}"))
  data.frame(predicted=predicted_probs, actual=predicted_classes)
}

# these give the same prevalence but different AUC
df_beta_preds <- get_beta_preds(1, 2, 100000)
df_beta_preds <- get_beta_preds(1.5, 3, 100000)

df_beta_preds %>%
  mutate(predicted_interval=cut(predicted, seq(0,1,0.1), labels=FALSE)/10-0.05)%>%
  group_by(predicted_interval) %>%
  summarize(mean_actual=mean(actual)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(predicted_interval, mean_actual)) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.3) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline()+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 1)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1))
```

[image: sampling from beta distribution]

These give well-calibrated predictions but I don't know what the "population" AUC would be for a given beta distribution. In the code above, I generate probabilities and classes under two beta-distributions with the same expected mean - these give different AUCs with large samples, so I assume that there is some relationship between (alpha, beta) and the AUC when classes are sampled directly from the given probabilities.

I have no idea how to either

1. Force the predicted probabilities in the first approach to be well-calibrated
2. Calculate the expected AUC given the use of alpha and beta in a beta distribution to sample probabilities (and assuming that these probabilities are well-calibrated)

Help regarding either of these would be great. My objective would be to input a given prevalence and AUC, and get calibrated predicted probabilities and classes in return.

Comment: Not quite an answer to your specific question but I typically use one of three methods for scaling my predicted probabilities:

1. a model based scaling technique (platt scaling or isotonic regression)
2. adjust the predicted probabilities based on the known incidence rate
3. if it's a logistic regression model or other linear model you can just adjust the intercept of the model....

I compared these in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/brshallo/24338a87b33e5d2ac98d200b1ccecfc5 (which was created in service of a tangentially related blog post topic). Maybe can layer one on sim method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied example code you linked to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422926/generate-synthetic-data-given-auc) and then applied platt scaling to the final step:

```r
library(tidyverse)

auc <- 0.95

t <- sqrt(log(1/(1-auc)**2))
z <- t-((2.515517 + 0.802853*t + 0.0103328*t**2) / 
          (1 + 1.432788*t + 0.189269*t**2 + 0.001308*t**3))
d <- z*sqrt(2)

n <- 10000
x <- c(rnorm(n/2, mean = 0), rnorm(n/2, mean = d))
y <- c(rep(0, n/2), rep(1, n/2))

data <- tibble(outcome = y, score = x)

# Applying Platt scaling to predictions / scores
model <- glm(outcome ~ score, family = "binomial", data = data)

df_preds <- bind_cols(
  data,
  # inverse logit of predictions from logistic regression model
  tibble(score_scaled = plogis(predict(model, newdata = data)))
) %>% 
  mutate(score_interval = cut(score_scaled, seq(0, 1, 0.1), lables = FALSE))

df_preds %>%
  group_by(score_interval) %>%
  summarize(mean_actual = mean(outcome),
            mean_score = mean(score_scaled)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mean_score, mean_actual)) +
  geom_line(aes(mean_actual, mean_actual, colour = "calibrated"))+
  geom_line(alpha=0.3, group = 1) +
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1))
```

[image]

```r
library(AUC)

auc(roc(x, as.factor(y)))
#> [1] 0.9496194
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: AUC is all about how well ordered / ranked the data is -- it doesn't care if the predictions are a probability, a log-odds, or anything. Here's a link to a gif + talk I gave where I explain AUC in my preferred way of thinking about it: https://twitter.com/brshallo/status/1292921952139644928?s=20&t=hU0zg1mwTLQcqor5pv2CxA

Comment: Perfect - thanks Bryan!